# A property of real sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that there is no sequence $x_1, x_2, x_3, ....$  of numbers in $[0,1]$ such that for any $1 \leq k \leq n$ there is $1 \leq i \leq n$ for which $x_i \in [\frac{k-1}n, \frac kn]$.

**COMMENT:** 
The problem asks for a (infinite) sequence such that the first two numbers must be in different halves, The first three numbers must be in different thirds, the first four numbers must be in different fourths and so on.

It is known that no sequence of length more that 17 can satisfy these conditions !!  See [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/70_01_irregularities.pdf). However, the proof is messy. I was hoping that showing that there is no **infinite sequence** with this property is much easier. And that's why I am posting this question, to see if there is any simpler proof for the infinite case. If you have (an elementary) solution please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

See the following [related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19896/slick-proof-related-to-choosing-points-from-an-interval-in-order) mathoverflow post. I don't know if you'd count Steinhaus' argument as "much easier".